# Cannot push into array from inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Whenever I try to push into the pathItem array, the response is an empty array. What is happening?

```js
        const categories = await Cars.find().distinct("bodytype");
        let pathItem = [];
        categories.forEach(async (element) => {
          const countQuery = await Cars.countDocuments({
            bodytype: element,
          });
          const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(countQuery / 12);
          for(let count=1; count<=numberOfPages; count++) {
          const carPath = {paths: { cartype: element, pages: count }}
            pathItem.push(carPath)
          }
        });
        console.log(pathItem) // this returns an empty array
```

Comment: forEach will not wait for async calls. Use [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: You could also do this in parallel using `Promise.all`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. Didn't know forEach does not wait for async calls.

Comment: @greyShader can you please add an answer to your question to help future question visitors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what worked:

```js
        const categories = await Cars.find().distinct("bodytype");
        let pathItem = [];
        for(let elements of categories) {
          const countQuery = await Cars.countDocuments({
            bodytype: element,
          });
          const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(countQuery / 12);
          for(let count=1; count<=numberOfPages; count++) {
          const carPath = {paths: { cartype: element, pages: count }}
            pathItem.push(carPath)
          }
        });
        console.log(pathItem) // this does not returns an empty array anymore
```

As Tushar mentioned, forEach does not wait for async calls, so Mongoose requests were not fulfilled before the forEach exited each loop.